# How can I listen for message read event

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I am making a widget in which i display unread message count on the icon. I am listening for incoming messages, upon which i can increment the count, using the intent filter: 
"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"

I can also get the unread message count at any time by doing:

```
final Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, "read = 0", null, null);
int unreadMessagesCount = c.getCount();
```

But i dont want to keep calling that function periodically. Instead
if the user reads an unread message, I want to decrement the count on my widget icon. Is there a way i can set up a listener for 'message read event' i.e. if the user opens up an unread message?

Comment: Hi, do you have any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **BroadcastReceiver** to fix the problem.

Please reference the link :
http://javapapers.com/android/android-receive-sms-tutorial/

Comment: The example is about intercepting and reading incoming messages. I am not trying to simulate the message app. I am looking for a way to keep my widget UI updated under all circumstances. I.e. even if the user does not directly interact with the widget.